# Power save Sleep Mode Arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, power

I'm trying to use this example [link](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode)

source:

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>

/* Sleep Demo Serial
 * -----------------
 * Example code to demonstrate the sleep functions in an Arduino.
 *
 * use a resistor between RX and pin2. By default RX is pulled up to 5V
 * therefore, we can use a sequence of Serial data forcing RX to 0, what
 * will make pin2 go LOW activating INT0 external interrupt, bringing
 * the MCU back to life
 *
 * there is also a time counter that will put the MCU to sleep after 10 secs
 *
 * NOTE: when coming back from POWER-DOWN mode, it takes a bit
 *       until the system is functional at 100%!! (typically <1sec)
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2006 MacSimski 2006-12-30
 * Copyright (C) 2007 D. Cuartielles 2007-07-08 - Mexico DF
 *
 *  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 */

int wakePin = 2;                 // pin used for waking up
int sleepStatus = 0;             // variable to store a request for sleep
int count = 0;                   // counter

void wakeUpNow()        // here the interrupt is handled after wakeup
{
  // execute code here after wake-up before returning to the loop() function
  // timers and code using timers (serial.print and more...) will not work here.
  // we don't really need to execute any special functions here, since we
  // just want the thing to wake up
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(wakePin, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  /* Now it is time to enable an interrupt. In the function call
   * attachInterrupt(A, B, C)
   * A   can be either 0 or 1 for interrupts on pin 2 or 3.  
   *
   * B   Name of a function you want to execute while in interrupt A.
   *
   * C   Trigger mode of the interrupt pin. can be:
   *             LOW        a low level trigger
   *             CHANGE     a change in level trigger
   *             RISING     a rising edge of a level trigger
   *             FALLING    a falling edge of a level trigger
   *
   * In all but the IDLE sleep modes only LOW can be used.
   */

  attachInterrupt(0, wakeUpNow, LOW); // use interrupt 0 (pin 2) and run function
                                      // wakeUpNow when pin 2 gets LOW
}

void sleepNow()         // here we put the arduino to sleep
{
    /* Now is the time to set the sleep mode. In the Atmega8 datasheet
     * http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2486.pdf on page 35
     * there is a list of sleep modes which explains which clocks and
     * wake up sources are available in which sleep mode.
     *
     * In the avr/sleep.h file, the call names of these sleep modes are to be found:
     *
     * The 5 different modes are:
     *     SLEEP_MODE_IDLE         -the least power savings
     *     SLEEP_MODE_ADC
     *     SLEEP_MODE_PWR_SAVE
     *     SLEEP_MODE_STANDBY
     *     SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN     -the most power savings
     *
     * For now, we want as much power savings as possible, so we
     * choose the according
     * sleep mode: SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN
     *
     */  
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);   // sleep mode is set here

    sleep_enable();          // enables the sleep bit in the mcucr register
                             // so sleep is possible. just a safety pin

    /* Now it is time to enable an interrupt. We do it here so an
     * accidentally pushed interrupt button doesn't interrupt
     * our running program. if you want to be able to run
     * interrupt code besides the sleep function, place it in
     * setup() for example.
     *
     * In the function call attachInterrupt(A, B, C)
     * A   can be either 0 or 1 for interrupts on pin 2 or 3.  
     *
     * B   Name of a function you want to execute at interrupt for A.
     *
     * C   Trigger mode of the interrupt pin. can be:
     *             LOW        a low level triggers
     *             CHANGE     a change in level triggers
     *             RISING     a rising edge of a level triggers
     *             FALLING    a falling edge of a level triggers
     *
     * In all but the IDLE sleep modes only LOW can be used.
     */

    attachInterrupt(0,wakeUpNow, LOW); // use interrupt 0 (pin 2) and run function
                                       // wakeUpNow when pin 2 gets LOW

    sleep_mode();            // here the device is actually put to sleep!!
                             // THE PROGRAM CONTINUES FROM HERE AFTER WAKING UP

    sleep_disable();         // first thing after waking from sleep:
                             // disable sleep...
    detachInterrupt(0);      // disables interrupt 0 on pin 2 so the
                             // wakeUpNow code will not be executed
                             // during normal running time.

}

void loop()
{
  // display information about the counter
  Serial.print("Awake for ");
  Serial.print(count);
  Serial.println("sec");
  count++;
  delay(1000);                           // waits for a second

  // compute the serial input
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int val = Serial.read();
    if (val == 'S') {
      Serial.println("Serial: Entering Sleep mode");
      delay(100);     // this delay is needed, the sleep
                      //function will provoke a Serial error otherwise!!
      count = 0;
      sleepNow();     // sleep function called here
    }
    if (val == 'A') {
      Serial.println("Hola Caracola"); // classic dummy message
    }
  }

  // check if it should go to sleep because of time
  if (count >= 10) {
      Serial.println("Timer: Entering Sleep mode");
      delay(100);     // this delay is needed, the sleep
                      //function will provoke a Serial error otherwise!!
      count = 0;
      sleepNow();     // sleep function called here
  }
}
```

I'm using a Tester for test really efficient of power saving; I read only a power save of 2 mA. Is it possible the Arduino Mega saves only that in sleep mode? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need a bare ATmega chip if you want to go low power. Otherwise you are continuously powering the 16U2 serial–USB bridge, the 3.3 V regulator and the power LED.

Comment: how i can shut down the serial usb Bridge , the 3,3 regulator and led power?

Comment: By unsoldering them, or cutting their traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [a page about power saving](http://www.gammon.com.au/power). About the first suggestion on that page is to not use an Arduino "board" (particularly one with a USB interface chip, power LED and voltage regulator). They all take power - a lot of it. These boards are designed for prototyping, not low-power use in the field.

Something like this would be better:

[image: Bare-boned Arduino]

Of course, that isn't an Atmega2560 chip. They only come in surface-mount and will be hard to solder yourself. You may be able to get an Atmega2560 board in minimal form. Or downgrade to a smaller processor that you can assemble yourself. The Atmega644P comes in PDIP which is easy enough to work with.

If you don't need all that RAM and program memory, you could go down to an Atmega328P which are easy to work with and can get down to 100 nA power consumption under the right circumstances.

---

You could conceivably do what Edgar Bonet suggested and cut traces on your Mega2560 board, but be warned that if you do that you won't be able to program the board via the USB interface afterwards. You can still program via the ICSP socket however, if you have a suitable programmer.

---

> What are you using as resonator there?

This one - I can't remember where I got it from.

[image: Resonator]

The Arduino Uno has a resonator on it for the main chip (not a crystal) so using a resonator is fine.

Comment: Nice information. What are you using as resonator there? The only one I know is using xtal+2cap

Comment: See amended answer.